# How to program 3D in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d

I want to program in OpenGL in 3D (have a special screen and glasses).

What do I have to do for that?

(options, code, ..?)

Comment: What kind of 3d screen and glasses?

Comment: shutter glasses and a screen by acer

Comment: Is that an autostereoscopic monitor? They're hell of expensive...

Comment: we have shutterglasses by envidia, there is a thing that synchronise the glasses, - the screen is 250€ :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really help you with own experience, but you should find some resources by searching the Internet for "stereoscopic opengl".

For example, [the "Stereoscopic OpenGL Tutorial" on gali-3d.com](http://www.gali-3d.com/archive/articles/StereoOpenGL/StereoscopicOpenGLTutorial.php) recommends the following rendering procedure:

> An OpenGL application with stereo capabilities must do following things:
>
> 1) Set the geometry for the view from left human eye
>   2) Set the left eye rendering buffers
>   3) Render the left eye image
>   4) Clear Z-buffer (if the same Z-buffer for left and right image is used)
>   5) Set the geometry for the view from right human eye
>   6) Set the right eye rendering buffers
>   7) Render the right eye image
>   8) Swap buffers

Comment: More in-depth view on stereoscopic rendering http://developer.download.nvidia.com/whitepapers/2010/NVIDIA%203D%20Vision%20Automatic.pdf (not just specific to nvidia's technology)

Comment: @Blam: Great paper on the topic. Although it doesn't say to not buy those nvidia glasses that flicker like a TV from 1950.

Comment: That will only work if your card is an *Nvidia Quadro*. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Opengl stereo 3d" and/or quadbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you graphic card: I suppose you have an **Nvidia Geforce** card. Sorry about that, but you won't be able to use [Quad Buffers Stereo](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro_stereo_technology.html) as explained by AndiDog. It is only possible if you have a professional card named **Nvidia Quadro**.

The only way to achieve stereo using a Geforce, is to use Direct3D. Either by letting the driver do the stereo for you or by rendering two buffers and presenting them in a weird way to Direct3D. This is explained in the slides [The In and Out: Making Games Play Right with 3D Stereoscopic Technologies](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2009/GDC/GDC09-3DVision-The_In_and_Out.pdf) of GDC 2009.